# Is it possible to switch on JSLint checking in PhpStorm for Typescript files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, phpstorm, jslint

Switching on JSLint code quality in PhpStorm only seems to work with js-files. Can I also switch it on for typescript (ts) files?

Comment: You don't really want to run a JS linter against _TypeScript_, do you? You'd want a syntax-checker for TypeScript. A cursory googling suggests that [tslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint) exists but not as a plugin for *Storm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please vote for [WEB-10556](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10556) to have TSLint support included in WebStorm/PHPStorm. You can try configuring tslint as a filewatcher for your .ts files as suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10556#comment=27-747735